# Load Balancing VPN servers (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, load-balancing, haproxy, pptp

I am trying to load balance two VPN servers, that are located quite far from one another.

I am using Ubuntu with pptpd, is there anyway to load balance those two servers? So user connects pptp to the load balancer then that routes it to one of the other two servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HAProxy only has layer 4 (TCP) and layer7 (HTTP) modes, it can't handle the GRE tunnels that PPTP controls.

So in short, you can load-balance the control channel (with TCP mode), but not the actual tunnels.